# simplify if statement with stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a following stored procedure where i am repeating similar code. all i am doing is checking the condition based on Sample id1, sampleid2, and sample id3 to follow in similar fashion. The value of 'y' goes on till about it reaches 10, so it's going to be a big 'if' condition based statements. i was trying to see if a better solution could be put in place. thanks.

```
@select = 'select * from tbl Sample......'
if(x = 1 and y=1)
set @where = 'where Sample.id1 >=1 and <=10' 
if(x = 1 and y=2)
set @where = 'where Sample.id1 >=11 and <=20' 
if(x=2 and y=1)
set @where = 'where Sample.id2 >=1 and <= 10'
if(x=2 and y=2)
set @where = 'where Sample.id2 >=11 and <=20'
if(x=3 and y=1)
set @where = 'where Sample.id3 >=1 and <=10'
if(x=3 and y=2)
set @where = 'where Sample.id3 >=11 and <=20' //increment goes on 
exec(@select+@where)
```

Comment: are x and y parameters?

Comment: Show how **exactly** both `x` and `y` are used in `@where`. If there is a consistency you can use string concatenations to build the result dynamically.

Comment: well, they aren't exactly used, x and y are values passed based on dropdown list selection

Answer (score 3):

In general, if there is no easy correlation between the values of `x, y` and the filtered columns `id1, id2` etc, then you could move the where predicates into a table keyed by values of x and y, and then use this as a lookup to apply to your PROC. Assuming the `SPROC` is used heavily, the lookup table can be made permanent and indexed on your `x,y` input mapping columns.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.WhereMappings
(
    x INT,
    y INT,
    Predicate NVARCHAR(MAX),
    CONSTRAINT PK_MyWhereMappings PRIMARY KEY(x, y)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.WhereMappings(x, y, Predicate) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Sample.id1 > 5 and Sample.id2 <= 10'),
(1, 2, 'Sample.id1 > 7 and Sample.id2 <= 15'),
(2, 1, 'Sample.id2 > 2 and Sample.id3 <= 18');
```

Your proc then simplifies to:

```
CREATE PROC MyProc(@x INT, @y INT) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @predicate NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT TOP 1 @predicate = Predicate 
       FROM dbo.WhereMappings WHERE x = @x AND y = @y;
    -- TODO THROW if predicate not mapped
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM Sample WHERE ', @predicate);
    EXECUTE(@sql);
END;
```

**Re : What does this solve**

Although this hasn't necessarily reduced the complexity of the original queries, it does however allow for a data-only maintenance approach to the mappings, e.g. Admin UI screens could be written to maintain (and validate! think Sql Injection) the predicate mappings, without the need for direct modification to the SPROC.

**Edit**

After your edit, it does appear that there is a correlation between `x, y` and the filtered column and range used in the `idx` predicates, viz `x` sets the column, and `y` sets the range between.

In that case, simply append the value of `x` to an `id` column name stub, and multiply out the value of the `BETWEEN` clause to `y*10 - 9` to `y * 10`;

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but is't this the same thing what originally OP did, but with different outlook. There is if condition ( in terms of predicate), list of `ifs` ( with extra `table` to maintain) and dynamic `query` to execute.

Comment: OP edited his original question, after which it became apparent that there may be a consistent correlation between the input variables and the predicate mapping, which would obviously be more direct than abstracting the predicates to a mapping table.

Comment: @stuart: is there any way i could replace Sample.id1 with say id2 or id3 dynamically based on the (x,y) condition.

Comment: If you can confirm in your original post that `x` is the suffix which needs to be applied to the `id*` column, and that y determines the range `(y * 10 - 9, y * 10)`, and that all the `idx` columns are all integer types then I believe you have a number of useful answers already.

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like this:

```
select 
   * 
from 
  tbl Sample
where
    (@x=1 and @y=1 and Sample.id1>=..and Sample.id1<=..) --(or you could use between)
    OR (@x=1 and @y=2 and Sample.id1>=..and Sample.id1<=..)
..
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set @select = 'select * from tbl Sample......'
set @where = 'where Sample.id'+convert(nvarchar(10),@x)+' >=....and <=...' 
exec(@select+@where)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use another sql table which will have information of all these condition like shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Then use join in your sql query like.(Assume above table has name **Limit**

```
select * from tbl Sample smpl
inner join Limit lmt
on @x=lmt.x and @y=lmt.y and  
( 
    (@x=1 and smpl.id1 >= lmt.Min_limit and smpl.id1 <=lmt.Max_limit) or 
    (@x=2 and smpl.id2 >= lmt.Min_limit and smpl.id2 <=lmt.Max_limit) or 
    (@x=3 and smpl.id3 >= lmt.Min_limit and smpl.id3 <=lmt.Max_limit)
)
```

In this I have tried to avoid dynamic query.

Comment: It seems unfortunately that OP also selects the column (`idX`) on which to apply the predicate dynamically as well.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to find a relation between inputs and outputs and in this case I found this way:

```
SET @where = 'WHERE Sample.id{0} >= {1} + 1 and <= {1} + 10'
SET @where = REPLACE(@where, '{0}', CAST(x AS varchar(5)))
SET @where = REPLACE(@where, '{1}', CAST((y - 1) AS varchar(5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
SET @where = 'where Sample.id' + CAST(@x AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' between ' +
              CAST((@y - 1) * 10 + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' and ' + 
              CAST(@y * 10 AS VARCHAR(10))
```